# User-defined function for numpy outer

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very long numpy array, but let's say it looks like this:

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([0.001, 0.02, 0.021])
```

I would like to access two elements at a time all the way down the array and perform an operation on them. For example, I want to do this:

```
np.cos(arr1[0])*np.cos(arr1[1])
np.cos(arr1[0])*np.cos(arr1[2])
np.cos(arr1[1])*np.cos(arr1[2])
```

I'm familiar with the function "outer", and I can use it for subtraction:

```
>>> np.subtract.outer(arr1, arr1)
array([[ 0.   , -0.019, -0.02 ],
       [ 0.019,  0.   , -0.001],
       [ 0.02 ,  0.001,  0.   ]])
```

How can I feed my own function into numpy's outer?

EDIT: based on a question in the comments, I'd like the function to return something like this:

I'd like the same pattern as that is returned by numpy's outer function.

```
array([[ np.cos(arr1[0])*np.cos(arr1[0]), np.cos(arr1[0])*np.cos(arr1[1]), np.cos(arr1[0])*np.cos(arr1[2]) ],

[ np.cos(arr1[1])*np.cos(arr1[0]), np.cos(arr1[1])*np.cos(arr1[1]), np.cos(arr1[1])*np.cos(arr1[2]) ],

[ np.cos(arr1[2])*np.cos(arr1[0]), np.cos(arr1[2])*np.cos(arr1[1]), np.cos(arr1[2])*np.cos(arr1[2]) ]])
```

Comment: Is there a pattern on how you are selecting the pairs of elements?

Comment: Please see the edit @Divakar, I couldn't fit my answer in the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numpy [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with ufuncs if you're doing mathematic operations that you want to vectorize.

```
arr1 = np.array([0.001, 0.02, 0.021])
cos_a = np.cos(arr1)
out = cos_a * cos_a[:,None] #rows * cols
```

Comment: Is it possible to compute f(a,b) rather than cos(a)*cos(b)?

Comment: @Anvit multiply is an existing [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html), but you can create your own with `np.vectorize`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`np.multiply.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) on the `cosine` computed values -

```
cos_a = np.cos(arr1)
out = np.multiply.outer(cos_a, cos_a) # Or simply np.outer()
```

Comment: Is it possible to compute f(a,b) rather than cos(a)*cos(b)?